# glewInit Segfault with GLEW 2.0

Tags: c, opengl, segmentation-fault, glfw, glew

I'm trying to write a simple program that just opens a window with GLEW 2.0 and GLFW 3, but am being met with a segfault...

Here is my source:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                      
#include <GL/glew.h>                                                    
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>                                                 

int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                       
    const int height = 100;                                             
    const int width = 100;                                              

    if (!glfwInit()) {                                                  
        printf("Glfw failed to init\n");                                
        return -1;                                                      
    }                                                                   

    // 4x antialiasing                                                  
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);                                    

    // We want OpenGL 3.3                                               
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);                      
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);                               

    // We don't want the old OpenGL                                     
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);      

    GLFWwindow* window;                                                 
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);

    if (window == NULL) {                                               
        printf("GLFW Failed to open a window. "                         
               "Intel GPUs don't support 3.3\n");                       
        glfwTerminate();                                                
        return -1;                                                      
    }                                                                   

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);                                     
    glewExperimental = 1;                                               
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {                                        
        printf("GLEW Failed to initialize.\n");                         
        return -1;                                                      
    }                                                                   

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);                

    do {                                                                
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);                                        
        glfwPollEvents();                                               

    } while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&      
    glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );                               
}
```

I compile this with

```
gcc test.c -g -lGLEW -lglfw -o test
```

And receive a segfault upon running the program. Using `gdb`, a backtrace on the segfault gives

```
0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
1  0x00007ffff7ba02a7 in glxewInit () from /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.2.0
2  0x00007ffff7ba87a3 in glewInit () from /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.2.0
3  0x0000555555554bd4 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf18) at test.c:39
```

I am on Ubuntu 17.04, and I installed glew/glfw with Ubuntus pacakge manager with

```
sudo apt-get install libglew2.0 libglew-dev libglfw3 libglfw3-dev
```

I was following this tutorial [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/). If it makes any difference, I don't have a desktop manager or a compositor running. I'm using i3wm. However, the segfault still occurs when running alongside the compton compositor.

Lastly, just so I can provide some extra info, the `ldd` shows the linked libraries of `test` as

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc44ce9000)
libGLEW.so.2.0 => /usr/lib64/libGLEW.so.2.0 (0x00007f8e53dc9000)
libglfw.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so.3 (0x00007f8e53b86000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8e537bf000)
libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f8e5351b000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8e53313000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8e53008000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8e52e04000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f8e52acb000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8e528ad000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f8e526a2000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f8e5249f000)
libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f8e52297000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f8e5208d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055e0ef28b000)
libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007f8e51e5d000)
libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007f8e51b8f000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f8e5196d000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f8e5175b000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f8e5154f000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f8e51349000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f8e51145000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f8e50f3f000)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try compatibility profile. I think I remember there were some problems with GLEW and core profile on Windows.

Comment: How can I enable "compatibility profile?". Sorry, this is on Linux.

Comment: You can find that in GLFW docs. [Change `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE` to `GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`.](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.2/window.html)

Comment: That worked! If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Do you have any more info as to why this is a problem? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is a bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/glew/patches/40/) saying that core profile was broken in GLEW until 2.0.0.

Thus, you should update the GLEW. If that won't work, switch to compatibility profile by replacing `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE` flag with `GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`.

Comment: Still confused why it says "fixed in the glew 2.0 release", since I'm using 2.0